に vs で　for way / manner?
''こんな感じに寛げる''
Hey another question again. In regards to doing actions how does the ni particle here work?
Would it be something similar to ''計画通りに'' or am I completely off the tracks? And at what points would one use the ni particle this way?　Why not use the で particle to explain how one does something like ''生で食べた''?

こんな感じに and こんな感じで are interchangeable here. This に is the に to turn a na-/no-adjective to adverbs, like in 陽気に歌う or 幸せに暮らす. Many words in this category only take either に or で, but a few words take both. For example, while 幸せで暮らす sounds unnatural, 健康に暮らす and 健康で暮らす both sounds okay to me.
(By the way, In English, this type of に roughly corresponds to "-ly", but its use is also somewhat inconsistent. We say "slowly" or "deeply" but not "fastly" or "bluely". Ultimately, we have to be familiar with common usage patterns.)

I would say that the main reason we don't say "bluely" is because it isn't clear how a colour could describe a manner of doing something.

@KarlKnechtel English speakers would say so, but I can see no structural difference between 壁を青く塗る and 穴を深く掘る...

Would it be fair to translate the ''に'' as ''in this way'' for adverbs like ''こんな感じに'' ?

@HoodIntercooledSubaru Yes, こんな感じに and このように are interchangeable, except that the former sounds relatively informal. You can translate them as "this way" or "like this".

I see, thanks for the comment
